# How to detect DOM element resize which happens due to asynchronous web font loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element containing text with font family to set to custom font which is specified in CSS via @font-face attribute. Since fonts are loaded only after they are being used in visible text on the page there is some time interval when div element is displayed with default font family. I need to perform element size measurements and currently I do it right away after element was added to the DOM. If font is not loaded yet I get initial size values which become incorrect after font family specified in CSS was loaded. So my question is how can I detect this and perform re-measure text again?
The only solution which came to mind is to use [font loading API](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-font-loading/#dom-fontfaceset-load). I use check method to see if font is ready and if not I listen to the ready event to perform text measure again. Is there better/more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Why you would want to do this may I ask? I guess you want to correctly get the size of the div element, is that right?

Comment: I display html text on top of svg via foreignobject and I need to "cut out" text element background from one svg shape and I am doing this using mask. So basically I do this to calculate rectangular mask size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect size changes in DOM elements, let's use [Resize Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

The steps are:

- Create a ResizeObserver, in which a callback with provided size changes will be called.
- Attach that observer to the element you want to correctly get the size.